# download text of an article in google news

Tags: nlp, web-crawler, selenium-webdriver, google-search-api, google-news

I'd like to do some natural language processing (nlp) mining based on news.

google has a smart way of extracting a useful text from news articles. that's the text it displays in google news. is there an easy way to download that text rather then copy the displayed text from google news then find that text in the original html and extract the div with that text?

Comment: when i did a search on the subject. there are a lot of answers and articles on how to use apis to get search result. I'm asking on how to get useful text not just the search results.